# Websocket Lambda Python and Angular

Tags: python, angular, websocket, aws-lambda

Guys I want to create a websocket api for realtime update of my records in a table.

I am using python lambda and angular for my project.

lets say I have this Book Record table :

```
Id |  Book name | Desc
1  |    bn1     | dec1
2  |    bn2     | dec2
3  |    bn3     | dec3
```

and what i want is to create a websocket for realtime update of my table in angular if there are changes.

so i am not familiar with websocket both frontend and backend
. please give me any tutorial related to this THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you already have a websocket server up and running.
What you need to do in angular is:
First you need to install socket.io-client

```
npm install socket.io-client
```

Then you need to create a service, you can call it `web-socket.service.ts`, you will need to import socket.io-client and Observable

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WebSocketService {
  // your service's logic
}
```

Now, inside your service you have to declare a variable to hold your socket connection

```
socket: any
```

Create a constructor and initialize your socket connection

```
  constructor() {
    this.socket = io('your web socket url')
  }
```

Create a function for listening to the web socket server

```
  listen(eventName: string) {
    return new Observable((subscriber) => {
      this.socket.on(eventName, data => {
        subscriber.next(data)
      })
    })
  }
```

and a function to emit to the web socket server if needed

```
  emit(eventName, data) {
    this.socket.emit(eventName, data)
  }
```

Finally you just inject the service where you what to use it for example inside app component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  constructor(private webSocketService: WebSocketService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.webSocketService.listen('your event name').subscribe(data => console.log(data))
  }
}
```

you can find all the code in the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-je3obn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)
I couldn't get socket-io to work in stackblitz but I think the code will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. My problem is websocket server up and running. Do u know how to do that in lambda/serverless framework? Im confused on how to return a data there and does it really return a record in a specific intervals

Comment: I never used python for the backend, but I use nodejs and I can point to some resources if you wanna get started with aws lambda/serverless/nodejs.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71cd5XerKss
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/websocket/

Comment: does websocket server returns a data in a given interval or it only returns a new data whenever an action is triggered?

Comment: Web sockets gives you the ability to things with real time data, which mean data on the server is always in sync with data on the client. can you explain what you mean by "data in a given interval" ?

Comment: well im confused on how will the web socket updates my table because from what ive read so far (chat app docs) its like an event driven and real time updates which means i have to specifiy or create an event that will trigger the update. What i want is like automatic update of my table without any action/event needed to trigger? is it possible in websocket? sorry cuz i have so many questions I am a newbie -_- thanks again

Comment: Even tho web sockets are labeled as automatic, but you will have to create events on the server side. for example you create an event that emits every time your data changes. on the client side, you are gonna listen to that event and update your table accordingly. I think you will have to do quite a bit of research to fully understand the concept behind web sockets.

Comment: have you encountered CORS issues while connecting to websocket server?

Comment: yes sure, you will just have to enable CORS in your backend. this accurse when your backend and your frontend are on the same ip:port.